# Unable to import events from Firebase Project in Google Ads

Tags: firebase

I have linked my Firebase Project with my Google Ads account, but, I am not to imports any events while setting up app conversions in the Google Ads account. It's been more than 24 hours. I would appreciate if anyone could let me know how can I resolve this issue. I attached the screenshots of the same for your reference. Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]